# Java and android testing methodology

Tags: java, android, testing, junit, compilation

I have a question about technology or methodology out there that I can use to test my code fast & simply. Recently I came across the difficulty & frustration regarding to testing my code when I was working on an android project. Everytime when i wanted to test my code, i had to re-compile whole project again and wait for emulator to re-install application which at least takes 40~50 seconds just to check a bit of code working fine. Are there any way that I can compile or test just a small portion of code / 1 ~ 2 methods working without having to re-compile whole project every time? Also which one is the latest and most widely used among the industries?

=====================================

Additional question. I've done some research on JUnit testing of java but is JUnit what i'm looking for? or is it different kind of testing technology

Comment: Unit testing is an indispensable part of a sound testing strategy, and that's also why [JUnit is part of the standard Android development system](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/index.html).  A well thought out test plan will eliminate much of the compile-deploy-fail frustration you're having now.

Comment: Thanks for reply fvu, yup, i understand what u are saying but since project is always expanding, i really needed some other better way of testing my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make a search about Robotium. it provides you to do blackbox testing.

http://testdroid.com/tech/54/automated-ui-testing-android-applications-robotium

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Robolectric](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/) is what You are looking for. You can use JUnit to test only java code that doesn't use methods from android sdk.

Answer (score 0):

have you considered using [AndroidTestCase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/AndroidTestCase.html)? JUnit can only be used to non-android specific function, but this does the job for your Android-specific code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very detailed account for android testing available at:

http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html

This includes basic as well as activity testing and is built on top of JUnit.

Answer (score 0):

For people that don't want to use Roboticum and such, but just stick with Eclipse built-in JUnit testing, this is what I would recommend:

Have three projects:

- AndroidProject
- AndroidProject.test
- AndroidProject.test.android

In your AndroidProject.test project you only test Models, Controllers and such which exclusively uses Java-libraries. So no Android Logcats, Toasts, or things like `Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches())` [`android.util.Patterns`] (which validates a String URL).

In your AndroidProject.test.android project you test the Activities, Services, Model-classes that use Android libraries like the Pattern-validation mentioned above, etc.

To be able to use Eclipse `Run As` -> `JUnit Test` for your JUnit test project you have to do some set-up however, like removing the `Android API` from each individual Test class, using the `junit.framework.Assert` and `org.junit.Test` imports, etc. For a full step-by-step guide to reproduce what I have done to make it work, I refer to my own Stackoverflow-post that I've made:

[JUnit Test Android classes without being forced to start the (slow) Emulator.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23828337/android-junit-testing-models-controllers-which-only-use-java-imports-without)